# Setting ffmpeg properly in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

I am following this website for ffmpeg tutorial: http://dranger.com
I tried to compile the programs after  setting up ffmpeg in ubuntu by looking on some online videos but none of them worked. Some times GCC gives me undefined reference error and sometimes header not found error. I looked on some of the answers on SO that said that we need to do some change in the code as the new api is not backwards compatible but still GCC gives me undefined reference error.
Here is the code that I am trying to compile:

```
    // tutorial01.c
// Code based on a tutorial by Martin Bohme (boehme@inb.uni-luebeckREMOVETHIS.de)
// Tested on Gentoo, CVS version 5/01/07 compiled with GCC 4.1.1
// With updates from https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial
// Updates tested on:
// LAVC 54.59.100, LAVF 54.29.104, LSWS 2.1.101 
// on GCC 4.7.2 in Debian February 2015

// A small sample program that shows how to use libavformat and libavcodec to
// read video from a file.
//
// Use
//
// gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lz
//
// to build (assuming libavformat and libavcodec are correctly installed
// your system).
//
// Run using
//
// tutorial01 myvideofile.mpg
//
// to write the first five frames from "myvideofile.mpg" to disk in PPM
// format.

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// compatibility with newer API
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc avcodec_alloc_frame
#define av_frame_free avcodec_free_frame
#endif

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame) {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Initalizing these to NULL prevents segfaults!
  AVFormatContext   *pFormatCtx = NULL;
  int               i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext    *pCodecCtxOrig = NULL;
  AVCodecContext    *pCodecCtx = NULL;
  AVCodec           *pCodec = NULL;
  AVFrame           *pFrame = NULL;
  AVFrame           *pFrameRGB = NULL;
  AVPacket          packet;
  int               frameFinished;
  int               numBytes;
  uint8_t           *buffer = NULL;
  struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtxOrig=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }
  // Copy context
  pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
  if(avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");
    return -1; // Error copying codec context
  }

  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=av_frame_alloc();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameRGB=av_frame_alloc();
  if(pFrameRGB==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);
  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // initialize SWS context for software scaling
  sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
               pCodecCtx->height,
               pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
               pCodecCtx->width,
               pCodecCtx->height,
               PIX_FMT_RGB24,
               SWS_BILINEAR,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL
               );

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
    sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
          pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

    // Save the frame to disk
    if(++i<=5)
      SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_frame_free(&pFrame);

  // Close the codecs
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtxOrig);

  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the command I use to compile:

```
gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lz
```

Comment: Why don't you just install from PPA? Here is the [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/install-ffmpeg-3-1-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/)

Comment: I had installed it through ppa but still GCC gives me undefined reference error

Comment: Please post your code and command that you are using to compile the program. Also what error are you getting?

Comment: I have edited the question, please check the code.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Install the libraries first `sudo apt install libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev` and the use `gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lz -lavutil`

Comment: I tried above on my machine and your code is compiling without any errors.

Comment: I tried to recompile the source after installing the libraries you specified but still I am getting error. Here is the error that I am getting: [link]http://dpaste.com/2CD699W

Comment: `PIX_FMT_RGB24` is now `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24`. The dranger tutorials are based on an older version of ffmpeg so it's a bit hit and miss until you find the right values and functions. There's new ways of doing stuff in ffmpeg now to years ago.

Comment: On another not, the best docs are in the source code you can download, build and install from the ffmpeg.org site. In the main source directory you will find `ffplay.c`.

Comment: Thankyou all. It worked like a charm.

Comment: I installed the needed libraries, then compiled the posted code using: `gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic   -c myprog.c -o myprog.o`  the result was 54: warning: conversion to 'size_t' from 'int' for the statement: fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);
 AND 95: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions for statement: for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) AND   133: warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' for statement: buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));  Not a clean compile.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression:  `sizeof(uint8_t)` has a value of 1 so has no effect on the value sent to `malloc()`.  3) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this kind of statement: `if(pFrameRGB==NULL)` is fraught with bad possibilities.  the most common problem is a keypunch error where only one '=' is typed.  strongly suggest always place the literal on the left so such an error would be caught by the compiler.  Also, a better method of writing the statement would be: `if( !pFrameRGB )`